# Treeview from TextBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, treeview

I have a **"Load"** button and a `TextBox` on a form. I want when the user clicks the **"Load"** button on the form all the file and sub directories that i have typed in the `TextBox` to put them on a treeview. I can't find a way to do this. I am using `vb.net` at coding.

Comment: Try [VB.Net - TreeView Control - TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_treeview.htm) Or _How to Create a TreeView File Browser Component in VB.NET_ [Part 1](http://glassocean.net/how-to-create-a-treeview-file-browser-component-in-vb-net/) [Part 2](http://glassocean.net/how-to-create-a-treeview-file-browser-component-in-vb-net-part-2/)

Comment: I checked it but there is nothing like this or similar there.